# How to accurately measure time in c++?

Tags: c++, time

I want to measure the execution time of a function very accurately, in picoseconds. Can it be so precise in C++? The methods I currently know to measure time are:

1. __rdtscp()
2. std::chrono clock
3. clock.h clock_t

Does anyone know how accurate these three functions can be? Which one can achieve picosecond time measurement, if all not, is there any way to reduce noise and make time measurement more accurate?

target system is Linux version 4.15.0-122-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-010) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)) #124~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP

Comment: How do you think a C++ method is going to measure time in picoseconds when you have no hardware for it? Accuracy is implementation defined on Widows/MSVC it measures in nanoseconds but minimal step could be 100ns or more. If you need high accuracy you'll need to buy hardware that can supply it and use its libraries.

Comment: Even if you _could_ meassure time that accurately, the meassure would still be flawed, because your pc does a lot more than execute a single function. For a useful meassure you need could run the function several thousand or million times and average the results. This way you don't even need to meassure this precisely.

Comment: Do you really need pico second resolution? On a 4ghz cpu 1 nanosecond is only 4 clock cycles, os scheduling vagaries will make your code's execution time vary by much more than 4 clock cycles

Comment: To beat microseconds you usually need specialized hardware.

Comment: It may not be necessary to reach the picosecond level, but which method is currently the most accurate?

Comment: On Linux, read [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), but don't expect better than a few microseconds of accuracy, unless you can spend a lot of money on specialized hardware and driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No clock on a consumer grade computer is going to measure with picosecond accuracy.  The call to get the current time alone is going to take at least tens of nanoseconds.

However you can time your target in a loop and measure the entire elapsed time. Then compute the average time per iteration.  `<chrono>` allows you to easily do this and compute the results to picosecond precision:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using picoseconds = std::chrono::duration<long long, std::pico>;
    constexpr auto N = 1000;
    auto t0 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int repeat = 0; repeat < N; ++repeat)
    {
        // measure this
    }
    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto d = picoseconds{t1 - t0}/N;
    std::cout << d.count() << "ps\n";
}
```

If you really want to get precise, you can measure the loop overhead (being sure it isn't optimized away), and subtract that off your total prior to averaging.

```
for (int repeat = 0; repeat < N; ++repeat)
{
    // measure empty loop overhead
    asm volatile("");
}
```

The syntax for discouraging the optimizer from removing a loop is not portable.

Answer (score 1):

> How to accurately measure time in c++?

Most accurate standard way to measure time is to use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` or `std::chrono::steady_clock`.

There may exist a more accurate way provided by the system. To find out about that, the first step is to figure out what the target system is.

> Does anyone know how accurate these three functions can be?

Depends on implementation and potentially also hardware.

> Which one can achieve picosecond time measurement

Probably none of those in practice. The fastest CPU's have cycle times measured in hundreds of pico seconds.

Comment: The standard allows the `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` to be the same as `std::chrono::system_clock` which means it is prone to interruptions. Only `std::chrono::steady_clock` guarantees monotonic time.

Comment: std::chrono::high_resolution_clock is in nano-second precision at the moment according to [libstdc++-11.2.0 std::chrono::_V2::high_resolution_clock](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/libstdc++/api/a01599.html#gab70b8aea9f615520e4143e918de990e1)