# float outputs differently in different consoles

Tags: c++, c++17

I am running the same OpenGL executable in CLion and cmd, but they show different outputs. CLion shows the right number, cmd shows `inf` and sometimes the number. `cout` does the same.

(I've mitigated all ogl calls from the code since they're unnecessary)

The code to that is:

```cpp
int i = 0;
auto lastTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
while ... {
    auto currentTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    if (i % 10000 == 0) {
        auto deltaTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(currentTime - lastTime).count();
        printf("FPS: %10.0f\n", 1.0f / deltaTime);
    }
    i++;
    lastTime = currentTime;
}
```

[image]

CLion left, cmd right

Comment: Looks like division by 0

Comment: judging by this code you're measuring the time it takes to increment `i` once, calculate `i%10000` and compare it to zero?

Comment: there is more gl code after this like i stated, which i mitigated for reading ease. i'm measuring how long the opengl code needs to draw one frame and show it once every 10000 draws. but i assure you, the code afterwards has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: Try placing the definition of `currentTime` AND the update of `lastTime` within the block of the `if (i % 10000 == 0)`.   At present, the value of `deltaTime` will be the time it took to execute the last iteration of the `while` loop.

Comment: @pptaszni in cmd, yea, it is doing a division with 0 through `deltaTime`, but thats not the question, the question is why is it 0 in the first place, and that *only* in cmd.

Comment: Probably because the time it takes to execute a single iteration of the while loop (which only involves a small number of instructions) is less than the resolution of the high resolution clock - so getting a zero difference is feasible.

Comment: @Peter, i know, it's supposed to show only the last iteration and skip 9999. Spamming the console like that reduces the times the loop can run. outstream spamming is costly.

Comment: @Peter i was thinking that too. but why does it work in clion, and *not in cmd*? it's only the outstream thats redirected. the application runs just like any other. not even in a debugger.

Comment: Yeah, but it's also (probably) causing the time between iterations to be less than resolution of the high resolution clock, which causes your division by zero.  You're assuming - without evidence - that the measured time between iterations will be non-zero.   The fact it works in some environments but not others just means different environments have different overhead (so the time for an iteration is longer in some cases).

Comment: @Peter i tested your thesis by delaying the executing thread for the minimum time the resolution of the clock supports (1 nanosecond). it yields same results. it does work though if i do delay it for even longer than that. I'd appreciate if you post your comment as the answer with the added information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981643/how-to-accurately-measure-time-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4706785/peter) pointed out, the problem is that some iterations take less time than the resolution of the clock being used and that time in turn depends on the environment where the program is executed.
A solution to such problems could be to measure the time for X iterations  (10000 in the following example) and then calculate the average time:

```
int i = 0;
auto lastTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
while ... {
    if (++i == 10000) {
        auto currentTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto deltaTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<float>>(currentTime - lastTime).count();
        deltaTime /= 10000.0f; //average time for 1 iteration
        printf("FPS: %10.0f\n", 1.0f / deltaTime);
        lastTime = currentTime;
        i = 0; //reset counter to prevent overflow in long runs
    }
}
```