# How to measure the execution time of inlined functions in C++?

Tags: c++, profiling, c++20, execution-time

I have a bunch of functions that complete in a few nanoseconds and I want to measure their execution time to assess their performance.

The basic idea is very simple, take a timestamp, execute the same blocks of code in a loop many times, take another timestamp, calculate the difference between the timestamps and divide the value by the number of iterations.

It is all very simple, the problem is when I put the benchmarking code in the `main` function, the compiler recognizes that I do the same calculations and do nothing with the result, so it makes the loop no-operation. So I get very small numbers.

I have managed to make the code execute by faking a usage, it works in Visual Studio 2022 but I have failed to make it work in Code::Blocks (MSYS2 g++ compiler).

This method is difficult to reuse, since whenever I want to benchmark another function I have to copy-paste the same lines of code. So I made it a function, and this increases reusability but blows the numbers way up. A lot of my functions are inlined, and using the function to benchmark other functions the inline optimization is disregarded.

Minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using std::array;
using std::chrono::steady_clock;
using std::chrono::duration;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::function;
double d = 0.0;
float r = 0.0;

constexpr double DU = 1.0 / (uint64_t(1) << 52);
constexpr float FU = 1.0 / (1 << 23);
constexpr array<double, 10> LOG2_POLY9 = {
    -3.27179702e00,
    7.19195108e00,
    -7.34289702e00,
    5.01474324e00,
    -1.64079955e00,
    -3.25941179e-01,
    5.83100708e-01,
    -2.58134034e-01,
    5.44419681e-02,
    -4.66794032e-03,
};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... I>
inline double apply_poly_impl(double m1, const std::array<double, N>& data, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    double s = 0;
    double m = 1;
    ((s += std::get<I>(data) * m, m *= m1), ...);
    return s;
}

template <std::size_t N>
inline double apply_poly(double m1, const std::array<double, N>& data) {
    return apply_poly_impl(m1, data, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

inline float fast_log2_p9(float f) {
    uint32_t bits = std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(f);
    int e = ((bits >> 23) & 0xff) - 127;
    double m1 = 1 + (bits & 0x7fffff) * FU;
    double s = apply_poly(m1, LOG2_POLY9);
    return e + s;
}

template <typename T>
double timeit(const function<T(T)>& func, const vector<T>& values, int runs = 1048576){
    auto start = steady_clock::now();
    size_t len = values.size();
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
        func(values[i % len]);
    }
    auto end = steady_clock::now();
    duration<double, std::nano> time = end - start;
    return time.count() / runs;
}

int main()
{
    double r4096 = 1.0 / 4096;
    double n;
    vector<double> random_doubles(256);
    vector<float> random_floats(256);
    for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
        n = rand() % 4096 + (rand() % 4096) * r4096;
        random_doubles[j] = n;
        random_doubles[j] = float(n);
    }
    cout << std::setprecision(16);
    auto start = steady_clock::now();
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < 1048576; i++) {
        r = fast_log2_p9(random_floats[i % 256]);
    }
    auto end = steady_clock::now();
    duration<double, std::nano> time = end - start;
    r = fast_log2_p9(0.7413864135742188f);
    cout << "fast_log_p9: " << time.count() / 1048576 << " nanoseconds\n";
    cout << r << '\n';
    cout << timeit<float>(fast_log2_p9, random_floats);
}
```

Compiled in Visual Studio 2022 with the following flags:

```
/permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Release\" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Ob1 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc143.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:fast /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /std:c17 /Gd /Oi /MD /std:c++20 /FC /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Ot /Fp"x64\Release\exponentiation.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\Xeni> C:\Users\Xeni\source\repos\exponentiation\x64\Release\exponentiation.exe
fast_log_p9: 0.9078025817871094 nanoseconds
-0.4317024052143097
15.96231460571289
```

Compiled with Code::Blocks, commands:

```
g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -fomit-frame-pointer -fexpensive-optimizations -flto -O3 -m64 --std=c++20 -march=native -fext-numeric-literals  -c D:\MyScript\CodeBlocks\testapp\main.cpp -o obj\Release\main.o
g++.exe  -o bin\Release\testapp.exe obj\Release\main.o  -O3 -flto -s -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -static -m64
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Users\Xeni> D:\MyScript\CodeBlocks\testapp\bin\Release\testapp.exe
fast_log_p9: 9.5367431640625e-05 nanoseconds
-0.4317024052143097
7.897567749023438
```

So how can I measure the execution time of a code-block with all optimizations on with a method that is easily reusable?

---

For whatever it is worth I have benchmarked `std::log2` provided by Visual Studio 2022 and mine is clearly faster and as precise with `/fp:fast` flag:

```
    start = steady_clock::now();
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < 1048576; i++) {
        r = std::log2f(random_floats[i % 256]);
    }
    end = steady_clock::now();
    time = end - start;
    r = std::log2f(0.7413864135742188f);
    cout << "std::log2f: " << time.count() / 1048576 << " nanoseconds\n";
    cout << r << '\n';
```

```
fast_log2_p9: 0.9081840515136719 nanoseconds
-0.4317024052143097
std::log2f: 54.67109680175781 nanoseconds
-0.4317024052143097
```

Additionally, I use Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10 x64, it should be extremely obvious, and quick-bench.com doesn't use MSVC compiler. My functions use `inline`, I have just seen that with inline enabled my function clocked 41 nanoseconds, but after I removed the three inline keywords the function clocked 29 nanoseconds. There would be a very high error because I have only run it twice.

But clearly the benchmark disregards inline because disabling the inline should make the code run much slower, it doesn't.

And `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(r);` is used, while I don't know its exact purpose, clearly the optimization isn't enabled, and my question clearly stated that I want to measure the execution time of the function ***WITH ALL OPTIMIZATIONS ENABLED***, because of course I would use the code with all optimizations.

And while it is true CPU's don't execute C++ code and C++ functions aren't translated into a continuous sequence of instructions, clearly I am stating that I want to measure the time that a function would typically take to complete, an average across many runs that I should expect.

Comment: What I usually do is to sum up the return values of benchmarks functions, and print the (dummy) sum at the end. In your case, just use `r +=` and `d +=`.

Comment: You can disable inlining for functions you are interested in; see, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/3330407/580083. And then possibly use a regular profiler. Or, if the function definitions are in a different translation unit than where they are called from, inlining is typically not applied (in theory it can be with LTO, but LTO may need some special compilation procedure to keep the intermediate representation available).

Comment: But in all cases, be aware that time measurements are not for free. They have some overhead, which may be (even much) longer than a very fast function runtime. Here are some relevant discussions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64988014/580083 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/73837954/580083. One, therefore, typically does not measure a single function call, but many of them, and average the result at the end.

Comment: Interesting approach!? You get optimzed code which reduces the runtime consumption to something nearly like nothing. And you are not lucky with that, want to switch off the optimization to get "real" measurements but with the effect that you measure someting which is not real generated code. My question: Why?

Comment: For such microbenchmarks its best to use a library, like [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark).

Comment: @Chris: With https://quick-bench.com/ for online testing.

Comment: I usually find a test point, that's not being used, and hook up the oscilloscope to the test point.  Next, I write a 1 to the test point before the profile and a 0 at the end of the profiling.  Next, make it inside a forever loop (lot easier to deal with the o'scope when the code is running forever).  This is the most accurate method I have found so far.  Logic analyzers can be use similarly.

Comment: [As a note, your implementation is approximately 2.9x slower than `std::log2`](https://quick-bench.com/q/CPyHTXpaAN0XDWZhkXzpwuhCXwU), and presumably, less accurate as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Performance measurement of C++ code can be very hard.

The chief problem is compilers. CPU's do not execute your C++ code. They execute CPU instructions. Your C++ code is translated to CPU instructions. Modern compilers, as a fundamental part of their design, do not translate every fragment of C++ code to a unique contiguous sequence of CPU instructions.

Thus, your question "how much time does this function take" already starts with the assumption that the function corresponds to a sequence of CPU instructions, with a start and an end, and no other instructions in between.

To make things worse, even *if* the compiler would output such a sequence, a modern CPU doesn't care that much. Out-of-Order Execution has been a standard CPU feature for decades by now.

And what exactly is the end of an instruction? The time when the value is written back to memory? With modern CPU's, that might not even happen. The CPU core has a queue of outstanding writes, and a later write can make an earlier write moot.

Your basic idea is to insert C++ benchmarking code. This really, really interferes with your program. You are no longer measuring the original functions. You're measuring new functions. Note that the timing code is functionally unrelated. Your out-of-order CPU can detect that instructions for `steady_clock::now();` are unrelated to `fast_log2_p9`, so it can just decide to start with `fast_log2_p9` even though the C++ code says it shouldn't.

Because of this, the fundamental idea of this question is just flawed. If you care about nanoseconds, you need to understand pipelined, out-of-order CPU's, the effects of cache and memory, and other hardware realities.